# Convert C++ unsigned char to PHP code

Tags: php, c++, char, c-preprocessor, unsigned

I have the following piece of code written in C++.

But I'm converting my application to php, just to learning purpose.

And I have this small piece of code.

```
#define NETWORKMESSAGE_MAXSIZE 16384
unsigned char m_MsgBuf[NETWORKMESSAGE_MAXSIZE];
```

How I can reproduce this same code on PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As here : [W3](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_misc_pack.asp)

You can use PHP pack() Function like this :

```
<?php
echo pack("C3",80,72,80);
?>
```

And

```
<?php
echo pack("C*",80,72,80);
?>
```

Comment: I tried in many ways, but i dont have get a good solution to my problem. If you want to analyze, here is the code that i need to convert to php, my only problem is the unsigned char of `m_MsgBuf`. http://pastebin.com/hzX1A8mH

Comment: @DjowYeap i will check your problem again, if i found something new i will add here , but i suggest to ask the next problems of your codes in new questions.